# MySQL > find users with same interests

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure if what I want to do is actually doable purely in SQL, but let's try.

Let's assume 3 tables:

- user (id, username)
- topic (id, topicname)
- affinty (user, topic, affinity)

In the affinity table, I would store, for each user/topic, is affinity from -2 (hate this topic) to +2 (love this topic). Doing a ABS(affinity_u1 - affinity_u2) would give me, for a single topic, between 2 users, a score between 0 (perfect affinity) to 4 (big difference).

My question is, in SQL, how can I calculate how similar the interests from all the other users for all practices are so that I can rank them from almost the same interests as me to no common interest.

Sample input, 3 users, 3 topics, different affinities:

```
INSERT INTO affinity (user, topic, affinity) VALUES
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 2),
(3, 1, -1),
(1, 2, 2),
(2, 2, 1),
(3, 2, 0),
(1, 3, 1),
(2, 3, 2),
(3, 3, -2);
```

Assuming I am user 1, as an output I would expect:

```
SELECT other_user, overall_average_affinity_compared_to_me FROM...
Row1: 2, 0.66
Row2: 3, 2.66
```

(the closest other user to me is 2, with an average affinity delta of 0.66, then comes user 3, with an average affinity delta of 2.66).

(I don't really care actually about the value itself, just the ranking)

Please tell me if my question is not very clear

Comment: Please prepare sample input and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT u2.username, AVG(ABS(a1.affinity - a2.affinity)) similarity
    FROM `user` u1
    JOIN affinity a1
      ON a1.user = u1.id
    JOIN affinity a2
      ON a2.topic = a1.topic
     AND a2.user != a1.user
    JOIN `user` u2
      ON u2.id = a2.user
   WHERE u1.id = :user_id
GROUP BY u2.username
ORDER BY similarity
```

Without the username:

```
  SELECT a2.user, AVG(ABS(a1.affinity - a2.affinity)) similarity
    FROM affinity a1
    JOIN affinity a2
      ON a2.topic = a1.topic
     AND a2.user != a1.user
   WHERE a1.user = :user_id
GROUP BY a2.user
ORDER BY similarity
```

It is worth noting that this isn't a great way of comparing similarities in the event that users rank a varying number of topics.

Comment: If I don't need the username (just the id), does the query become simpler?